# Highlighting a <td> if two select inputs share a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

We've got a form that has several uniquely named  elements; but all of these elements share the same group of options (incl. name/id etc). The problem is, we need to alert the user with a warning (i.e; an asterisk, or a td turning to background-color red) if two selectors are set to the same option.

So as a quick example, we might have two different selectors;

```
<select name="ServiceName-1">
...options..
</select>

<select name="ServiceName-2">
...options..
</select>
```

The options all share ids and names. In short, if ServiceName-n shares a selected option id with any other ServiceName-n, we need to perform an action - like changing a td colour, or making a div with an asterisk in it visible.

Comment: I don't see any `td` in the code

Comment: "The options all share ids": ids have to be unique; no sharing. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more dynamic solution:

1. Get all the selects on the page, store and loop through them
2. See how many of the selects have the same value as the current one
3. When there is more than one with the same value, update the color of the parent `<td>`, otherwise, make it white.

You can run the following snippet to see it in action.

```js
$(function() {
  markDuplicates();
});

$("select").on("change", function() {
  markDuplicates();
});

function markDuplicates() {  
  //get all the selects on the page and store a collection
  var selectedValues = $("select");
  
  //loop through all the selects
  selectedValues.each(function() {
    color = "#FFF"; //set a default background color for the current select (white)
    var value = this.value; //store the current selected value
    
    //get all selects that match the current value
    var dupes = selectedValues.filter(function() {
      return this.value === value;
    });
    
    //if there's more than one with the selected value then we will have a new color for the td
    if (dupes.length > 1) {
      var color = dupes.find("option").filter(function() {
        return this.value === value;
      }).attr("data-color"); //get the value data-color from the selected value
    }
    
    //get the closest td and set its background color
    dupes.closest("td").css("backgroundColor", color);
  });
                           
}
```

```css
td { height: 50px; width: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="ServiceName-1">
        <option data-color="#F00">One</option>
        <option data-color="#0F0">Two</option>
        <option data-color="#00F">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="ServiceName-2">
        <option data-color="#F00">One</option>
        <option data-color="#0F0">Two</option>
        <option data-color="#00F">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="ServiceName-3">
        <option data-color="#F00">One</option>
        <option data-color="#0F0">Two</option>
        <option data-color="#00F">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="ServiceName-4">
        <option data-color="#F00">One</option>
        <option data-color="#0F0">Two</option>
        <option data-color="#00F">Three</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. I think others want to lynch me - so I greatly appreciate the help. Like I said, jQuery and Javascript are not even remotely my forté (I've purely worked backend previously, or in very basic HTML5/CSS3 front-end environments) - so again, thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[name*="ServiceName-"]').change(function(){
 if( $('[name="ServiceName-1"]').val()==$('[name="ServiceName-2"]').val() ) {
  $('.tdClass').css('background-color','yellow');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to trigger a function when the select fields are changed. So add the same `onchange` function to both select fields.

```
<select onchange="checkFields();" name="ServiceName-1">
```

Then create a Javascript function that compares the two select fields to see if they are the same. If they are, produce whatever error you want.

```
function checkFields() {
  var sel-1 = document.getElementsByName("ServiceName-1")[0];
  var sel-2 = document.getElementsByName("ServiceName-2")[0];
  if (sel-1.value == sel-2.value) {
    alert("Error!");
    /*Since I can't see the rest of your html, you will need to create a snippet here 
      that will make the tables red or whatever.*/
  }
}
```